# Preventing a Verse Linebreak within a Multicolumn Environment

Tags: pdftex, line-breaking, multicol, verse

I am trying to include a stanza of poetry with a multicolumn environment such that there is no break in the lines of the poem.

I had hoped that

```
\settowidth{\versewidth}{}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
```

would do this for me. But it hasn't.

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[3]
\settowidth{\versewidth}{Behind the clouds the sun is shining}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
\begin{footnotesize}
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Be still sad heart. stop repining, \\
Behind the clouds the sun is shining; \\
Yours is the common fate of all--- \\
Into each life some rain must fall.}}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{verse}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

with the output

[image]

Since I am using the `footnotesize` font for the verses, it seems there should be enough room under the paragraph to accomplish this, but this is not the case.

QUESTION: How may I increase the default width of the verse environment so that each line of verse appears unbroken under the paragraph? In this case, I am not opposed if the longest line extends slightly beyond the width of the column---although I'm not sure LaTeX will permit this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\settowidth{\versewidth}{\footnotesize \bfseries Behind the clouds the sun is shining}` to measure the right length of the longest line.

[image: a]

It was close call. The column width is 158.27 pt.

The verse width without `\bfseries` nor `\footnotesize` is 158.97pt,
slightly larger.

The correct verse width is 156.21 pt.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\begin{document}    
         
    \begin{multicols}{2}    
            
        \lipsum[3]
                
        \settowidth{\versewidth}{\footnotesize \bfseries Behind the clouds the sun is shining} % changed <<<<<<
        \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
                \footnotesize \bfseries \textcolor{red}{
                    Be still sad heart. stop repining, \\
                    Behind the clouds the sun is shining; \\
                    Yours is the common fate of all--- \\
                    Into each life some rain must fall.}        
        \end{verse}

    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```